# Deep Insert with web services

Tags: odata, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central

I need to insert headers and lines at the same time using the Business Central web services. The header gets inserted successfully but not the lines. (They just don't insert)

While looking online for this problem, I came across a few posts mentioning that **Deep Inserts** are only possible with the APIs.

I tried to find an article or a part of Microsoft's documentation that would mention this, but I can't seem to find anything. This makes me wonder whether it really is only possible with the APIs.

So my question is: Are the Deep Inserts really only possible using the Business Central APIs ?

Answer (score 1):

I had an experience in make a deep insert only using APIs, by simply publishing an API page (with the source table set to the header) having also a page-part for the lines.

I think this could be a good example on how to do it: https://www.kauffmann.nl/2020/07/01/deep-insert-with-business-central-apis-part-2/